# How to apply texture image to my 3D model in metaio

Tags: android, 3d, augmented-reality, blender, metaio

My ***texture image*** (.png file) seems to be ignored somehow and my ***3D model*** (.obj file) is displayed in one colour. Both built in Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that I haven't included a **MTL** file in my project...